# Tata photon device is not working after deleting files in Control Panel

Tags: windows-7, lan, internet-connection

I have deleted some files in Control Panel to increase the performance of the laptop. Now LAN is not working or due to some other problem Tata photon device is not working.

1. I tried in Network and Internet troubleshoot option. I am getting:

   > A network cable is not properly plugged in or may be broken

   but the same device working fine in other laptop.
2. I checked the Options of photon device its saying Card Information, Port status, Modem information, Register Status, CD Status are all "Not ok".

Comment: Which files did you delete?

Comment: Try reinstalling photon plus drivers

Comment: Thanks a lot, Re installed the device and now its working fine